# sucessfully authenticated but can't write in firebase database using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

There is a question similar to this but it has been stalled. so, I've put up this one.

what I have done is created a flutter app in android studio. I can successfully login but can't update the database.

Here's my code
Firebase initialization

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference userRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
```

The code to authenticate and write to the database

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void registerNewUser(BuildContext context) async {
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailTextEditingController.text,
                password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
            .catchError((errMsg) {
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      //save user to database

      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      };

      userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);
      displayToastMessage(
          "Congratulation, your account has been created", context);
    }
```

The firebase rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

At this point the user is authenticated, however, in the real-time database, no values are being updated?
As i debug it reaches the point `Map userDataMap = {` and completely skips
`"name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(), "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(), "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),}`
The debugger console is pretty normal, I don't get any errors. Is there any way I can debug this more extensively? or what am I missing?

[image: Authenticated Users]

[image: Empty database]

Comment: Does it create the toast - User created?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes it does `Congratulation, your account has been created`

Comment: Does it work if you write a simpler value, like `userRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set("Hello world");`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, it doesn't work. However I can write to firestore database, I am migrating to it from realtime database.

Comment: Check the log output of your app for errors when it runns the `set(userDataMap)` statement

Comment: There just isn't any errors, it completely skips the part where there is `set(userDataMap)`. I am using FireStore instead, it's working fine.

Comment: same too,How solve that error

Comment: Given some other reports, I think this is because your database is hosted in a non-default location - which means you need to specify the URL in your app code. See my answer here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68026450

Comment: You are absolutely correct! The issue was with the url not being specific.

Comment: Good to hear that fixed it @pannam 