# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter Application

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, feed

I want to create feeds like that of Facebook in my flutter application. I have stored data in a realtime database of flutter which is as follows:

[image: Database Structure].

The keys p1, p2, p3, ... store three values, named dp, feed and name. The dp and feed are image file URLs from Firebase Storage.

The code that I am writing to retrieve them is as follows:

```
class _DoodleHomeState extends State<DoodleHome> {
 
  List<Posts> postList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(postList.length); //This prints the output 0

    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("feeds");
    print("At line 38"); //This prints the output


    postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      print("At line 42"); //This does not print
      var KEYS = snap.value.keys;
      var DATA = snap.value;


      postList.clear();

      for(var singleKey in KEYS){
        Posts post = new Posts(
          DATA[singleKey]['dp'],
          DATA[singleKey]['feed'], 
          DATA[singleKey]['name'], 
        );
        setState(() {
          postList.add(post);

        });
      }
      print(postList.length); //This does not print
      setState(() {


      });
    });

  }
```

In this code, I have mentioned in the comments that the control does not go into the `postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap)` function, and the code does not seem to move forward from that point, because the `print("At line 42")` statement isn't working.
I have not yet added the code to show those files in my flutter application because I don't know if they are getting stored or not. Every answer and YouTube video that I have found works through similar logic by using `.once()` and `.then()` functions.

The firebase dependencies of my project in pubspec.yaml file are as follows:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  firebase_database: ^4.4.0
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Where is your database hosted? If it's not in the US, you 'll have to specify the URL in your code as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console/68026450#68026450

Comment: It worked! I added the URL as specified. Thank you so much for this reference and your help.

Comment: Good to hear this fixed it. .   The engineering team is investigating why this doesn't surface as an error message btw.

Comment: I hope they can figure it out. Without a precise error message, there's no way to know where the problem occurs, especially for beginners.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely not the experience we want you to have. But we've been unable to reproduce it. Can you do me a favor and check in your `google-services.json` file, and tell me what value there is in there for `"firebase_url"`?

Comment: I couldn't find `"firebase_url"` in my `google-services.json` file. Looked twice. Is that a problem with my project?

Comment: Ah, that would explain indeed. It probably means that you downloaded your `google-services.json` *before* you created the database in the console. You can redownload it, to get the value in there, but the in-code solution you have now works too and is recommended. But it never shouldn't fail silently of course, so we'll keep looking.

Comment: Yes Sir you are right. I redownloaded the google services file. Here is the firebase url: ` "https://my-first-project-442ea-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app"`