# Reading data from Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have read a few posts but I am confused. This is the first time I've used firebase realtime database (I've used firestore without much problems upto now).

My data looks like the following:
[image]

It gets automatically updated. I have to make a flutter app now which can read this data and write to this individual document as well. I just can get past a simple read. Could use some help please. My simple code is attached to a button. I want to then tap into the data and make a listview.

```
onPressed: () async {
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  fb.child('turk****fault-rtdb/1buFA3****am6w32mDGon****kCeLs/Form Responses 1/').once()
      .then((DataSnapshot data) {
    print("Value: ${data.value}"); // prints null
    print("Key: ${data.key}"); // prints Form Response 1
  }).catchError((onError){
    if (kDebugMode) print (onError);
  });
```

How can I tap into each 'record' and get details out of it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks off:

```
fb.child('turk****fault-rtdb/1buFA3****am6w32mDGon****kCeLs/Form Responses 1/').once()
```

You can't pass the database URL itself into the `child()` call.

Try this instead:

```
final fb = FirebaseDatabase("your database URL").reference()
fb.child('Form Responses 1').once()...
```

Also see: [Why is the Firebase Realtime Database's data appearing as null in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console/68026450#68026450)

Comment: `final fb = FirebaseDatabase("your database URL").reference()` seems not to work in flutter? (Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. )

Comment: Hmm.... it might be `FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "your database URL")` in that case. See https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.html