# App not reading or writing to Firebase Real time database Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to read and write data into firebase in flutter android. I used to have it working with a different app 2 years back but now it doesnt work

I have followed every guidelines for authenticating to firebase

This is my file structure

[image]

I have added google-services.json and everything just like how its specified in SDK instructions while creating Firebase android app in FIrebase project.

This is my app level build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.crud_sqlite_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.8'


}
```

and this is my project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me. I am not able to read or write to firebase using the below code

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users");

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _updateInviteeList();
  }

  _updateInviteeList() async{


    print("Setting");
    await ref.set({
      "name": "John",
      "age": 18,
      "address": {
        "line1": "100 Mountain View"
      }
    });
    print("Set complete");


  }

  Widget _buildNote(Invitee invitee) {
    print(invitee.id);
     .........
     .....
     .....
```

I do not know what is going wrong. The _updateToFirebase() is called in initState() of my home screen. I know the above function is async and i am not using await to call it but atleast it should write the map to the firebase.

Please help me.

Comment: How do you configure your Firebase project's options in the Flutter app? If that is through a `google-services.json` file, the most common problem these days is that you downloaded this file before creating the database and thus the file misses the necessary configuration data. If that is indeed the cause of the problem, you can either download an updated file from the console and add it to your Android project, or you can specify the database URL in code `FirebaseDatabase("database URL here").reference...`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321682 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68026450

Comment: I tried like you said. DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "https://-----------.firebaseio.com").ref("users"); .. This did not solve the problem. I also downloaded the google-services.json file once again and updated it. That too didn't solve my problem. 

PS... The above mentioned line of code shows its deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
I/TetheringManager( 2808): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.crud_sqlite_app
W/NetworkRequest( 2808): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 2808): No App Check token for request.

-----This is the error I get.. Also when trying to signInAnonymously i get this Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Comment: Are you [enforcing App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/enable-enforcement) for the Realtime Database in this project? If not, tat "No App Check token for request." is not relevant (the SDK just can't know that, so it logs a warning).

Comment: Okay, Lets forget about No App Check token. I still dont know why I get no auth token

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me. The issue was that the application was not connected to the Firebase real-time database, and all of the results I was receiving were being cached on the device.

Use this section of the documentation to check whether the database is connected in case you have a similar issue [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

In my case, the reason it wasn't connected was that you need to include the url of the database found in the firebase console in your code when referencing any real-time database on Flutter that is located outside of Central America. As a result:

```
final firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase(
        databaseURL:
            "https://yourfirebaseproject.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/")
    .reference()
    .child("Items");
```

I hope this can fix your problem.