# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This is the error that I'm facing, I tried different fixes from the internet but nothing rly worked!
I'm using flutter on android studio to build an app
the Error is:

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://flutter-fp-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

one of the codes I put related to it is

`DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");`

and

in another dart

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void registerNewUser(BuildContext context) async
  {
    final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailTextEditingController.text,
        password: passwordTextEditingController.text
    ).catchError((errMsg){
      displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    })).user;

if(firebaseUser != null) //user created
      {
        //save user info to datebase
      

      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      };

      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);

      displayToastMessage("Congratulations, your account has been created!", context);
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);

      }
    else
      {
        // error occured - display error message
        displayToastMessage("New user has not been created! please try again later.", context);
      }
```

I also tried to update the json file, even though it has the right code it didnt work :(

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "80090510867",
    "firebase_url": "https://flutter-fp-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    "project_id": "flutter-fp",
    "storage_bucket": "flutter-fp.appspot.com"
  },
```

pls help :)

Comment: Updating the JSON file *should* work, but alternative you can also specify the URL in your code: `FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "your database URL").reference()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console/68026450#68026450

Comment: yeah idk y updating the JSON didn't work somehow,
but the alternative solution worked!!!!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you updated google-services.json file.

-> Build / Clear Project
-> Rebuild Project

Comment: That worked!. However, I didn't find the clean project choice.
so I went with gradlew clean and gradlew build from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- It happened to me 2 times
- 1st time it works with specifying the url like this

> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://vax-in-60807-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")

- 2nd time I have to change my project(firebase) and connect with new one

Comment: thanks, idk y .getInstance doesn't work with me it doesn't recognize it. However, the code Frank added worked perfectly, FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "your database URL")

Comment: oh its android studio code and you are using flutter my bad