# Flutter realtime firebase is not working. No errors shown but data is not inserted into the database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question have been asked before but I have tried it and still not working. That's why I post this question. Recreated the project many times and still cannot get it.

I initialize the firebase.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users');
```

I just wanted to insert data into the realtime database with this testing code

```
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      userRef.child('testing').push().set({'testing1': 'hello', 'testing2': 'bye'});
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

I have added the required file at the

Application/android/app/google-service.json

I also added the required SDK as needed for firebase.
I have also tested the playground for Realtime Firebase

[Playground for realtime firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD75q.png)

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you download the `google-services.json` before you created the database instance in the Firebase console by any chance. That's quite common and means that the database URL is missing from the `json` file, and the SDK may not function correctly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console/68026450#68026450

Comment: Please add new google-services.json file after you added rules to firebase db and replace with old one and  try again.

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it worked like a charm. thank you for the advice.

Comment: I replaced google-services.json to a new one and  use this code. Problem solved
FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "your database URL").reference()

Comment: In my case everything works perfectly fine on the Android studio emulator, however, nothing works on the real device, the real device cant read or write data to my real-time database. can anyone please have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem once with IOS because I was using flutterfire cli and it generated the google-services.json and GoogleService-info.plist files so what I did just I deleted those and then downloaded them again from the project settings and It worked