# flutterfire RTDB failed on android but work in web

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

After create new flutter app I try to follow flutterfire as documented in https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs. I use firebase auth, realtime database, and it only work when using flutter run in web browser, but not working in android. I try to print console to check if firebase is initiate in android and it show result that firebase is initiate, I also found firebase auth successfuly login, but I can't get any result from console from Realtime Database ( in android only ), is there any clue to debug it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I use:

```
class SpcStreamer {
  final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  Stream<List<SpesialisModel>> getSpesialisStream() {
    print('call getspesialis');
    final specStrean = _database.child('specialities');
    Query qrdoc = specStrean.orderByChild('ondisplay').equalTo('yes');
    final snap = qrdoc.onValue;
    final spcStream = snap.map((event) {
      final specMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
          event.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
      final specList = specMap.entries.map((e) {
        return SpesialisModel.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(e.value));
      }).toList();
      return specList;
    });
    return spcStream;
  }
}
```

and use the class in screen ..

```
                   StreamBuilder(
                   stream: SpcStreamer().getSpesialisStream(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        final splist = <SizedBox>[];
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final dsSpesial =
                              snapshot.data as List<SpesialisModel>;
                          splist.addAll(
                            dsSpesial.map(
                              (spc) {
                                return SizedBox(
                                  width: 250,
                                  height: 250,
                                  child: SpecialityCard(
                                    specid: spc.id!,
                                    specialtyName: spc.specialityName,
                                    specialtyDoctorCount:
                                        spc.specialityDoctorCount,
                                    specialtyImagePath: spc.specialityImagePath,
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 180,
                          child: ScrollConfiguration(
                            behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
                            child: ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              children: splist,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Works in web but not in android.

Comment: How are you adding the configuration for Android. My first guess is that you may have downloaded the `google-services.json` file before creating the database in the console, which means the database URL is not in the JSON files, and the SDK can't find your project. If that's the cause, you can specify the URL in the code instead, which works for all platforms: `final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance('database URL here').ref();`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025986/why-is-the-firebase-realtime-databases-data-appearing-as-null-in-the-console

Comment: i have that in firebase_options.dart, it was generated when i use  cli command flutterfire configure

Comment: Hmm... that worked for me the one time I tried it, so I'd it's correct for you too. Then again: it might be worth checking the URL in that Dart code then and seeing if it matches what is showing in the Firebase console. I'm focusing on this, because the rest of the code is shared between the platforms (I assume).

Comment: i already check the url few times and tested i got correct user uid as respond from firebase auth, but not from RTDB

Comment: Hmm... in that case I don't know. I hope somebody else spots the problem. 

Comment: in main function, maybe you forget to `Firebase.initializeApp()` ?

Comment: i initializeApp()  before, that is the reason i can get user uid from firebase auth, and there is no issue in web, but android.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, because the Map can work in web but not in android. i update the following Stream ..

```
final specMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
          event.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

to

```
final specMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
          event.snapshot.value as Map);
```

Web still show result in this Map<String,Dynamic>, but in android will result null